# Linux keeps deleting files

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

I have a Linux server (VM on Azure) that only 4 people have access and no one has been doing anything on it. However, there are some files that keep disappearing from some folders.

Is there anyone for me to find out why and how? Any commands that I should use on the terminal? I don't understand much of Linux, hence the question.

Comment: I'm afraid this is way, way too broad for us to be able to answer. The obvious thing is that someone else, or one of the 4 people you mention, has been deleting files and not telling you. What files? Random files? Specific files? Who owns them? What permissions do they have? Are they in `/tmp`? Somewhere else? The more information you can give us, the better the chances someone might be able to help.

Comment: shutdown. clone the disk to another separate disk. resume operation. we need more detail. what files? is this a webserver? ...or a server of any type?

Answer (score 6):

```bash
$ systemctl enable auditd
```

Use this for the `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` file:

```
## First rule - delete all
-D

## Increase the buffers to survive stress events.
## Make this bigger for busy systems
# -b 8192

# set from 8k to 1mb
-b 1048576


# 2 is shutdown, 1 is runlevel 1

-f 1

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S unlink -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S unlink,unlinkat,rename,renameat,rmdir -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink,unlinkat,rename,renameat,rmdir -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete

-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k watchXXX
```

```bash
$ service auditd restart
```

Then check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for indication of when and how your file(s) are getting deleted.  Search in `audit.log` for `delete` per the `-k delete` flag.  Change the syntax of `delete` to `DELETEXYZ` to make it easier to find in the audit.log if it suits you.

You can also do a watch via `-w` and label those audit records using  `-k watchXYZ`.

Parsing audit.log is easier said than done but the data would/should be in there regarding your file/folder deletion if you just search for the `delete` label per `-k delete` in the rules file.

**note:** If you get nothing, remove or tweak `-F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset` but be prepared for a huge audit.log in a very short time.